# wordpress css code for cover image problem

Tags: css, wordpress, image, image-resizing

I am trying to set cover photo in wordpress home page.
Desktop version works fine, but tablet and mobile version just crop image in viewer, mobile even more that in tablet.
I want to have full size photo on all devices.
I am using astra wordpress plugin.
Is there css code that i can insert to get same proportion on all devices?

Thanks,
B.

I tried code i found online

```
html {
   min-height: 100%;
   background-image: url(image.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

and it works for desktop version, but tablet and mobile still shrink.

Comment: What do you mean by crop? If it is a vertical screen and you use a horizontal image, the left and right part will not be visible You 'cover' the image so it streches to full height and keep proportions. With 'center center' you define which part to be seen.

Comment: now i used vertical image and results are different.